# Deriving E=mc^2 from hollow box with mass M and photon

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I'm working on a problem to derive E=mc^2 using conservation of momentum and center of mass.  We have a hollow block of length L and mass M.  A photon passes through taking mass m and adding it to the other side at speed C.  Here's what I've got:

The momentum p of the photon si the same as that of the box.  So we have that E/C, which is the momentum of the photon=$m_{box}v_{box}$.  The time it takes would be L/C and hence the distance would be vL/C.  Let's say that the box moved a distance of x after the photon came in.  What is that distance x?

Here's what I have done so far:

-The system is the box and the mass m being transported by the photon from one end to the other.

My reference point I will set is the edge of the box where the mass m is before displacement.  Therefore,

$$X_{CoM}=1/M(LM/2)=L/2$$

The center of mass is L/2 from the reference point.

To find the distance x, I set L/2 as the following:

$$L/2=1/M(M(L/2-x)+m(L-x))$$

I think there's something wrong with this equation because at the end I'm getting that x=mL/M+m.  Can someone help me out here?  Thanks in advance

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/178976/47511

Comment: You have a confusing way of putting things. Photons are massless. Yes they have energy, but they have zero rest mass.